# HttpClient doesn't return if empty post response is

Tags: xamarin.ios, dotnet-httpclient, cfnetwork

My program is written on Xamarin for iOS. Xamarin has a choice of network stack to use:

- managed,
- CFNetwork based,
- NSUrlSession based.

I make a POST request to my REST service and get an OK(200) response with empty body. Everything happens as I planned.

But when I use the CFNetworkHandler the HttpClient.PostAsync never complete. If response body is not empty everything goes well.

Is this a well known bug or something else?

Comment: You can use the [ModernHttpClient](https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient) to have a try.

Comment: @Kevin, this is not solution.